# Maintaining print CSS stylesheet files

Tags: css, printing, printing-web-page

How do you usually handle changes to screen and print CSS files? I typically have one screen CSS and one print CSS file and for the most part the I would copy the contents of screen CSS to print CSS file and then modify some properties, classes or ids, maybe set some display:none to certain classes etc.

The problem is, while working on a site or web app I make numerous changes to screen CSS and usually forget about print CSS then I have to sync them from time to time and I just don't think that the most optimal way.

Answer (score 0):

For print stylesheets I tend to also apply the `media="screen"` stylesheet to the `media="print"` as well as a second stylesheet that appears later, which essentially, just removes the elements I don't want to print.

It's a fairly simplistic approach, though, and only works to any potential if it's regularly reviewed, so I couple it with a policy of *always* revising (or, at least, checking) it when I revise the screen-stylesheet.

Comment: so in a sense similar to what I do..we'll see if anyone comes up with a more "sturdy" approach.